# Widget/Badge for UX Stackexchange for our resume/portfolio sites?

Tags: support, promotion

Tried searching the meta-questions and didn't find this, though easily could've missed. Please point me in the right direction and close this if so.

I'm wondering if there's a widget/badge available to members to put on their web sites?  One of those linked thingys that show a few basic profile facts or picture and promotes this site at the same time?

Thanks -

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's something that shows your name, rep, badges, and gravatar; it's called "flair". There's a [tab on your profile page](https://ux.stackexchange.com/users/523/susan-r?tab=flair) with the different types; the default looks like this:

[image: Susan's flair]

You can link it to your profile or the main site to help promote it; I linked the example above to the UX homepage